# Does Cassandra w/ CQL3 support "WITH CLUSTERING ORDER" option?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm using Cassandra 1.1.0 with CQL 3.0.

When create table, the following error occurs.
I referred to http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-evolutions

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE timeseries (
        ...   event_type text,
        ...   insertion_time timestamp,
        ...   event blob,
        ...   PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
        ... ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY insertion_time DESC;
Bad Request: line 6:22 mismatched input 'ORDER' expecting '='
```

Is this invalid query?
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER` syntax was only added in Cassandra 1.1.1 (just released a few days ago), so it won't work in 1.1.0.

Also, though, that example is missing some parentheses around the clustering definition. You want:

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries (
   event_type text,
   insertion_time timestamp,
   event blob,
   PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC);
```

Hope that helps. I'll let the author of that article know about the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread the documentation. But it 1.1.1 has just been released! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can see it with details in this link
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html

Comment: Unfortunately the link does not provide any information on the WITH CLUSTERING ORDER option. Or at least, I failed to find anything on that matter.